# Stop NodeJS' readdir from leaking memory

Tags: node.js, memory, memory-leaks, directory

I recently wrote an Interval in NodeJS, which checks the content of a folder every X Seconds. It is async, so that it runs beside the rest of the code to update indexes and contents.
OS is Debian 9 with node v10.15.2 and npm 5.8.0.

```
  return await new Promise(resolve => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("Checking for new files...")
      fs.readdir("folder", (err,files) => {
        if(files.length != cur_files.length){
          console.log("New files detected!")
          updateIndexes(files);
        }else{
          console.log("Folder is up-to-date!")
        }
      });
    },10000);
  });
}
```

I noticed that, while testing with a low Interval timer, it slowly but steadily raises memory usage by ~0.1MB every few minutes. I know that this isn't much with a big interval, but it will add up over time if I run it without restarting.

The other part of the code already uses a Stream for frequent file read/writes, do I have to do something similar here with readdir?
Is this a bug or just bad practice?

Thanks in advance!

BR Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you returning a Promise that never resolves?

The Garbage Collector will periodically reap unreferenced objects, but putting that code inside an unresolved Promise like that may stop the GC from collecting them, because it thinks it needs them for when the Promise resolves.

Try this:

```
return (() => {
  let fileCount = 0 // hide variable because State Machine
  return setInterval(() => {
      console.log("Checking for new files...")
      fs.readdir("folder", (err,files) => {
        if(files.length != fileCount){
          console.log("New files detected!")
          fileCount = files.length;
          updateIndexes(files); 
        }else{
          console.log("Folder is up-to-date!")
        }
      });
    },10000)
  })()
}
```

It is a state machine, and it hides its state (fileCount) inside a closure.

This returns a handle to something you can cancel with `cancelInterval`.